# In Pyramid, is it safe to have a python global variable that stores the db connection?

Tags: python, pyramid

It looks like this is what e.g. MongoEngine does.  The goal is to have model files be able to access the db without having to explicitly pass around the context.

Answer (score 2):

Pyramid has nothing to do with it. The global needs to handle whatever mechanism the WSGI server is using to serve your application.

For instance, most servers use a separate thread per request, so your global variable needs to be threadsafe. gunicorn and gevent are served using greenlets, which is a different mechanic.

A lot of engines/orms support a threadlocal connection. This will allow you to access your connection as if it were a global variable, but it is a different variable in each thread. You just have to make sure to close the connection when the request is complete to avoid that connection spilling over into the next request in the same thread. This can be done easily using a Pyramid tween or several other patterns illustrated in the cookbook.